# How to lock memory of pointer in Delphi to read value only?

Tags: delphi, pointers, locking

I have some sample code as below. Please help me lock the pointer and do not allow update value at address of the pointer.

```
Var
    Mypointer : PShort;
Begin
    Mypointer := AllocMem(1024);
    FillMemory(Mypointer, 1024, 1); // <= how to do not allow change value of Mypointer and lock it.
```

Comment: Theoretically you can use VirtualProtect but you'll conflict with the memory manager. Hence allocate the memory outside the region of the manager yourself (VirtualAlloc ...).

Comment: Why do you ask? Yes you can use protection, but an attacker could change that.

Comment: Who says OP wants to protect against an attacker, might be another reason such as concurrent (thread) access. Need more info...

Comment: That was just a guess, and that's why I asked for more info.

Comment: Sorry, I have project that read data of images from file and set to pointer. Then, set to all objects to can use as read-only or edit value.
Because value in pointer can be edited by all objects, cannot control.
I want to lock pointer, get value is possible but set value is not.

Comment: I suspect your "objects" won't expect read-only data, so your approach will rather crash your program instead of letting it run on silently. Think about another way.